# flask, wtforms_alchemy, relationship, and annoying Unbound field not callable error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask, python, wtforms, and wtforms_alchemy

Why am I getting an 'Unboundfield not callable error'

When the line `data = ModelFormField(fields.FormField(TestRelationForm))` is present, and not otherwise?

```
from wtforms import fields
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

from app import app
from app import db

from app.models import *

ModelForm = model_form_factory(Form)

class TestRelationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TestRelation

    @classmethod
    def get_session():
        # this method should return sqlalchemy session
        return db.session

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    data = ModelFormField(fields.FormField(TestRelationForm))

    class Meta:
        model = Test

    @classmethod
    def get_session():
        # this method should return sqlalchemy session
        return db.session
```

In my handler, I'm calling form = TestForm(), so the form is instantiated... and I'm passing the instantiation through to the main template with the line: `return render_template("main.html", form=form)`

I don't even care about editing the form at this point, I just want The Test Form to also display the fields from TestRelationForm, like it's intended to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face palm.

It's

```
data = ModelFormField(TestRelationForm)
```

not

```
data = ModelFormField(fields.FormField(TestRelationForm))
```